# Regex: Remove everything except emoticons. how?

Tags: c#, regex, sentiment-analysis, emoticons

If I have string such as "I love my country :) :D. I like myself :P -_- .", how to remove everything except Emoticons - so the resulting string should be without any text ? 
Input String or text can be any type.

I am using Regex

```
Regex.Replace(str, "[A-Za-z]", "");
```

but it also remove "P""D" in ":D :P" smiley. What will be the Regex then?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow.. This smells very complicated.

Comment: IMHO, you should have a *database* of emoticons (such as an array) and simply iterate it testing if the string contains each emoticon. I'm a big fan of regex, but I don't believe this is the case for it.

Comment: Do you want to keep all of them http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons

Comment: Problem is, you can swap : for = and still have the same emoticon. Also some emoticons have the char before the 'eyes' and some people who've been on the net longer even add noses i.e. :D D: =D D= :-D D-: And depending on context, not all of them are emoticons! E.g. D: could be the start to a file path.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of emoticons so so you wil. end with a very long and over complicated regular expression but. In this case I think you only care of Two 'corrupted' emoticons after the replace. So if this is the case, this should work:

```
[ABCE-OQ-Za-oq-z]|(?<!:)D|(?<!:)[Pp]
```

This regular expresssion match on ABC, the range from E to O and then the ragne of Q to Z for lowercase letters it matches from a to o and from q to z. The key part in the regular expression is that it only matches D, P and p if the matched char is not preceded by a colon. This feature is called lookaround (or in this exact use case lookbehind).